# Use a custom SSLSocketFactory in WildFly 10

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, wildfly

I would like WildFly 10 to use a bespoke `SSLSocketFactory` so that I can implement some funky TLS ciphersuites as part of security research.

I've built a dummy factory that prints logs and passes them to the default provider. However, I can't get WildFly to use it.

I've added a security property `ssl.SocketFactory.provider=<my.class.name>` into the java.security file in my JRE. I've placed the JAR containing my implementation in the JRE's lib/ext directory.

I've tested that this worked by writing a small Java test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    System.out.println(factory.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

which correctly prints my provider name, when executed from the command line outside of WildFly.

Unfortunately, WildFly seems to ignore this setting. I've tried running WildFly with debug switched on (added `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.debug=ssl"` to my `standalone.conf` file), but there are no error messages about loading my provider.

WildFly is configured without a JAVA_HOME, so it's just using the `java` command to start the server.

How can I get WildFly 10 to use my SSL provider?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by creating a security provider that implements `"SSLContext.TLS"` . This provides me a hook to intercept how socket factories are constructed.

By placing this provider at the top of the java.security providers list, I can intercept the things I need and return different `SSLSocketFactory` or `SSLServerSocketFactory` instances.

Useful links:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Steps https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContextSpi.html